# Instalar versão específica de uma biblioteca com NPM

Tags: npm

Como faço para escolher a versão de uma biblioteca que desejo utilizar, com NPM?

Por exemplo

```
1.0.0
1.0.1
1.1.0
1.1.1
1.2.0
```

Se eu rodar `npm i nome-do-package`, ele instalará a versão `1.2.0`, por ser a última.

Mas como eu faria para instalar a versão `1.1.0` do package, visto que, sempre que instalo, vem a versão mais recente?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode usar o `@` para especificar a versão, dessa forma:

```
npm i nome-do-package@1.1.0
```

Comment: Bacana, é bem simples. Obrigado pela resposta +1

Comment: Excelente pergunta, vai ajudar muita gente com certeza!

Answer (score 6):

O comando abaixo permite instalar uma versão específica de um *package*.

```
npm install <package>@<version>
```

Ex: `npm install sax@0.1.1`

Pode ser que falhe caso a versão não tenha sido publicada no registro do *package*. Para verificar todas as versões, basta utilizar:

```
npm view <package> versions
```

Fonte: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: Ótima resposta! Não conhecia o `npm view`.